# Why can't my C++ classes use Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I'm working on a very basic C++ application using Qt5.6 with CMake. [Git Repo Here](https://github.com/DanielArnett/opencv-mjpg).

My problem? My `main.cpp` can `#include` Qt classes like `<QtCore/QObject>`, but my defined classes cannot.

```
error: QtCore/QObject: No such file or directory
```

I have downloaded the [latest version of Qt with Qt Creator here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/).

[image: Screenshot depicting the Qt Creator IDE with the error message "QtCore/QObject: No such file or directory" emanating from a user-defined header file.]

Could this be an improperly set up Qt environment? I don't understand how `main.cpp` can access Qt but my defined classes cannot.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(testproject)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

############ OpenCV PACKAGE #########
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
set(OpenCV_FIND_QUIETLY FALSE)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
qt5_wrap_cpp(tcp_hdr_moc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TcpServer.h)
# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(helloworld WIN32 main.cpp
    TcpServer.h TcpServer.cpp
    )
# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TcpServer.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TcpServer.h
    )
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QObject>
//#include "TcpServer.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString test = "Hello";
    QObject test2;
    int i = 0;
//    TcpServer server;
}
```

User defined class: TcpServer.cpp

```
#include "TcpServer.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtCore/QByteArray>
#include <QtCore/QtDebug>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

TcpServer::TcpServer(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    // whenever a user connects, it will emit signal
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
        this, SLOT(newConnection()));
    if (!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9999))
        qDebug() << "Server could not start";
    else
        qDebug() << "Server started!";
    vCapture = new VideoCapture(0);
}
void TcpServer::newConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    QByteArray ContentType = ("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" \
        "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n" \
        "Cache-Control: private\r\n" \
        "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--boundary\r\n");
    socket->write(ContentType);
    std::vector<uchar> buff;
    Mat img; //OpenCV Material
    while (1) {
        // Image to Byte Array via OPENCV Method
        buff.clear();buff.empty();
        vCapture->read(img); //Read from webcam

        //TODO set the compression parameters.
        imencode(".jpg", img, buff);
        std::string content(buff.begin(), buff.end());
        QByteArray CurrentImg(QByteArray::fromStdString(content));
        QByteArray BoundaryString = ("--boundary\r\n" \
            "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" \
            "Content-Length: ");
        BoundaryString.append(QString::number(CurrentImg.length()));
        BoundaryString.append("\r\n\r\n");

        socket->write(BoundaryString);
        socket->write(CurrentImg); // Write The Encoded Image
        socket->flush();
    }
}
```

User Defined Class Header which throws the error: TcpServer.h

```
#ifndef TCPSERVER_H
#define TCPSERVER_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"

using namespace cv;
class TcpServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TcpServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    void newConnection();
private:
    QTcpServer* server;
    VideoCapture* vCapture;
};

#endif
```

For reference I am working on these two related stack overflow questions.

[How to Create a HTTP MJPEG Streaming Server With QTcp-Server Sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064955/how-to-create-a-http-mjpeg-streaming-server-with-qtcp-server-sockets)

[Error while using QTcpSocket.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025383/error-while-using-qtcpsocket)

Comment: show the content of the project(CMake) file

Comment: It's all in the Git repository above. Here is the CMakeLists
https://github.com/DanielArnett/opencv-mjpg/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L3

Comment: It is a rule of Stack Overflow that code should be included into question post itself, not referenced to other site. See [ask] for more info.

Comment: I will go through the How to Ask, thank you for your feedback @Tsyvarev. The question has been updated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but why aren't you using a Qt Project? It uses QMake instead of CMake, and with better Qt support.

Comment: @user1887915 My team uses CMake, so it's easier for me to port existing projects. For this specific project I was having trouble including OpenCV, so I reverted to CMake.

Comment: @user1887915 Perhaps the best solution is to just switch to qmake, but I can't figure out how to include opencv with it....

Comment: `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig PKGCONFIG += opencv`  provided by http://stackoverflow.com/a/3517716/1887915

Comment: error: cannot find -lippicv

Comment: Side note: You're not supposed to `#include <QtModule/QClass>`: it hides project configuration issues and they surface during link time. You should `#include <QClass>` or simply `#include <QtModule>` as a whole. That way the project won't compile if the configuration is wrong. Any Qt examples that include `<QtModule/QClass>` are misleading.

Comment: I appreciate the note @KubaOber, thanks! The project has been updated.

Comment: @user1887915 I believe that is the way to link opencv on OSX. On Ubuntu Linux the appropriate way to link opencv is with `LIBS += \`pkg-config opencv --libs\``, according to this excellent intro to qt and opencv guide: https://code.google.com/archive/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/wikis/Documentation.wiki

Answer (score 4):

Add `find_package(Qt5Core)` in addition to `find_package(Qt5Widgets)` and add the following lines:

```
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

And do not forget to add `Qt5::Core` to the `target_link_libraries`.
BTW, I see you are using QtNetwork; you will have to make the same steps for that module too. And for every other module you will use.

Comment: Made changes, updated Github to match, still have the same error.

Comment: Also, when I try `find_package(Qt5Widgets Qt5Core)` I get the response `error: find_package called with invalid argument "Qt5Core"`, so I broke it up into 3 statements.

Comment: @DanielArnett, sorry about the mistake in the answer. Did you try to make a clean build?

Comment: Cleaned CMake and cleaned the build- still no luck.

Comment: @DanielArnett, try to add `REQUIRED` to `find_package` for Qt modules like you have it for OpenCV and make sure CMake is re-run.

Comment: Still no luck, cleaned everything and I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: @DanielArnett, well, it is next to impossible. If you did what you said then it found Qt — otherwise there would be errors on CMake run. And if it found Qt it is not possible that the includes weren't set. You CMake file is right, I've cloned your repo, removed opencv(I don't have it) and it compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks for going the distance. I've come to believe that it's a combination of my build environment and Qt/CMake compatibility issues. Switching to qmake now.